# Why is a common reference string needed in zero knowledge proofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Can we have a non-trivial language without a CRS? Why?

Comment: Does the [Swiss voting back door](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68003) answer this?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Yes, also a good elaborate example

Comment: Do you mean NIZKs?

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer I was not being specific, however if you have any insight on NIZK specifics then it would also be helpful

Comment: FWIW: My initial thinking was that it was similar to why we need an encryption key in an encryption scheme. As in it provides non-determinism @Occams_Trimmer

Comment: If interaction is allowed then there are quite a lot of examples: take any language in the classes PZK/SZK/CZK. However, only languages in BPP have NIZK proofs without CRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any language in the [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Variants_of_zero-knowledge) PZK (perfect zero-knowledge), SZK (statistical zero-knowledge) or CZK (computational zero-knowledge) have interactive protocols that are zero knowledge and don't require a CRS. Some of the interesting non-trivial languages in these classes are listed below. (I'd also recommend [this](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/complexityZK.pdf) beautiful survey by Vadhan)

- PZK: [Quadratic residuosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem), [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism)
- SZK: Quadratic non-residuosity, graph non-isomorphism, lattice problems like [CVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_(CVP))
- CZK: [Graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) (and in fact as Geoffroy points out any language in IP)

However, Oren [O] showed that only languages in BPP have NIZK proofs without CRS. You can find a proof sketch [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/gradcrypto2/NOTES/lecture17.pdf) (Lemma 1).

[O]: Oren. [On the cunning power of cheating verifiers: Some observations about zero knowledge proofs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568300) (behind a paywall unfortunately).

Comment: Is Honest-Verifier-Zero-Knowledge in CZK?

Comment: Since (assuming OWF) CZK = PSPACE = IP, every language that has an interactive proof, zero-knowledge or not, is in CZK.

Answer (score 8):

To complement a bit the answer of Occams_Trimmer: a CRS matters strongly for obtaining zero-knowledge proofs *with a small number of rounds* and *for a large class of languages*.

Without a CRS and without restriction on the number of rounds, as Occams_Trigger mentioned, we get the class CZK. This is a very large class: under the minimal assumption that one-way functions exist, it is actually equal to the huge class PSPACE. If we limit our attentions to zero-knowledge proofs with an *efficient* (polynomial time) prover, then it becomes equivalent to NP (i.e., essentially the class of all languages we care about).

However, without a CRS, it is much harder to get a small number of rounds: assuming only one-way functions, we need a superconstant number of rounds to get zero-knowledge proofs for NP. Assuming further the existence of collision-resistant hash functions, we can build [five rounds](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PSX/zkAK.pdf) zero-knowledge proofs for NP. This is essentially the best we can hope for: under black-box simulation, a 4-round zero-knowledge proof for NP would [collapse the polynomial hierarchy](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/265.pdf) (but there exists some candidate constructions based on exotic assumptions, such as knowledge-of-exponent assumptions or keyless multi-collision resistant hash functions, with non-black-box simulation). Even with non-black-box simulation, a 3-round ZK proof for NP would [break indistinguishability obfuscation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/167.pdf). Furthermore, 2-round ZK proofs can simply [not exist](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PSX/oren.pdf) for languages outside BPP.

In contrast, with a CRS, every language in NP has a *non-interactive* (1-round) zero-knowledge proof, under standard assumptions (e.g. factorization).